# Best practices when authenticating an API for long-term usage in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, jwt, token

I'm writing a mobile app, and would like to have the user sign in once and pretty much be set for life. From the rails side of things, I'm unsure what the best practice is for keeping track of sessions. One possible solution would be to hand out a JWT with a session ID. I would have a session table in the database, which would allow me to revoke sessions. The JWT would not have a built in expiry time.

Another option would be to use the built in rails session, and deal with the cookie on the app side. To me, this seems kind of hacky, and it's probably not a standard use case because sessions aren't included with api-only rails apps by default.

What's the best-practice way of doing this?

Comment: I like to use doorkeeper and set the token to not expire unless logging out. https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper

Comment: Have a look at this gem - https://github.com/Gokul595/api_guard#default-configuration.

Comment: @Aarthi Would that gem not be insecure for what I'm doing, considering I would have no expiry?

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery This is probably going to be what I end up doing. Oauth seems to be the way to go.